# Android CardView with weird border when transparent

Tags: android, android-cardview

I'm having some trouble with CardView transparency and card_elevation. Trying to use a CardView transparent the result is:

[image]

Without transparency:

[image]

What I'm trying to get is something like this:

[image]

Here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/eifell"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/newsCardView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="175dp"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#602B608A"
                card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you ever get a workaround for this? It looks like cards aren't designed to support background transparency: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78061

Comment: Hello Steve, no I'm just using RelativeLayout with a transparent background without shadow (elevation). When I found something I will post where.

Comment: @SteveBlackwell That is valid answer of this question. Thanks.

Comment: Question: Why do CardViews actually behave this way? Is there a Github issue to this effect?

Answer (score 20):

I know i am a bit late, but it's just because of card default elevation. Set it to zero to solve your problem.

```
app:cardElevation="0dp"
```

Comment: It's very inconvenience to have this by default. they just wasted 5-6 hours of mine just for this line. anw thanks for this

Comment: but how can you keep the shadow?

Comment: Then i will say you can't remove elevation and then then you will have to take some help from ViewOutlineProviders to solve that problem.

Comment: u saved my life

Answer (score 6):

Try this code:

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/newsCardView"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#602B608A"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:src="@drawable/fake_image" /> //REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR IMAGE
</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

If it not helped, provide whole xml code of your layout

Comment: Everything looks great on my device, try to update cardView library to com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.1

Comment: I'm using this version already, what android version did you tested?

Comment: Android 4.4.2 and Android 5.1.1

Comment: Can you send me a screenshot? There is not weird board on the cardview? tks

Comment: @StealthRabbi isn't SO about straightforward answers?

Comment: @Shujito It's not easy to understand and there's no explanation of the provided code or in what way it's an improvement over what the OP posted.

Comment: if you change cardCornerRadius you will see the artifact cRobot is talking about

Comment: settting `cardElevation` to 0 removed the border in my case

Answer (score 5):

That effect is not specific to `CardView`, but rather is an artifact of the method Android uses to render and transform material shadows on all `View`s since Lollipop and the introduction of Material Design. It can be observed on pretty much any `View` with the right attributes:

- A translucent/transparent background,
- A positive z-offset (`elevation` + `translationZ`),
- A `ViewOutlineProvider` that sets an `Outline` with a non-zero alpha.

To illustrate, this mock-up shows a plain `<View>` with a background that is a solid white round rectangle tinted with a translucent blue:

[image: Screenshot of a mock-up of the question's setup with a plain View.]

<sup>*Tower image modified from ["Eiffel Tower in Vintage Sepia"](https://www.flickr.com/photos/lennykphotography/25609006376) by [Lenny K Photography](https://www.flickr.com/photos/lennykphotography/), licensed under [CC BY 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/).*</sup>

Obviously, the stated criteria present a few different ways to disable the shadow altogether, so if you don't really need that but still need the elevation for z-ordering, for instance, you could simply set the `ViewOutlineProvider` to null. Or, if perhaps you also need the outline for clipping, you could implement a `ViewOutlineProvider` to set an `Outline` with zero alpha. However, if you need all of these things just without the shadow glitch, it seems that a workaround will be required since the platform apparently offers no way to fix that otherwise.<sup>*</sup>

This answer was originally a handful of "last resort"-type workarounds that were put together under my initial (incorrect) presumption that, except for a few high-level attributes, the shadows API was essentially inaccessible from the SDK. I cannot rightly recommend those old approaches anymore, but the overall method that I ended up with is a bit more complex than I'd intended for this post. However, neither can I rightly turn this answer into just an advertisement for [the utility library](https://github.com/zed-alpha/shadow-gadgets) I've put together from all of this, so I'm going to demonstrate the two core techniques I use to obtain clipped shadows, to give you something that you can get your hands on here, if you'd rather not fiddle with some shady stranger's unvetted GitHub repo.

---

<sup><sup>*</sup> After I'd figured out a decently robust technique for the general case, I created [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70227950) in order to share those findings. The question there has my reasoning regarding the platform statement, along with links to several other Stack Overflow posts with the same core issue, and the same lack of an actual fix.</sup>

#### Overview

Though the native shadows are pretty limited, Android's procedure for calculating and rendering them is relatively complex: two light sources are considered, an ambient and a spot; the shadows must adjust for any transformations that their `View`s might undergo, like scaling and rotation; newer versions support separate colors for each light source, per `View`; etc. For these and other reasons, I decided that it would be preferable to somehow copy the native shadows and clip those, rather than trying to draw correct ones ourselves from scratch.

This leads to the reason for the two separate techniques: the intrinsic shadows are a resultant property of the `RenderNode` class, but that's not available in the SDK until API level 29 ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RenderNode)). There are ways to use the equivalent class on older versions, but those are outside the scope of this answer, so an alternate method that uses empty `View`s is shown here to cover all relevant Android versions in these hands-on samples. The library uses this empty `View` method as a fallback, should there be any problems using `RenderNode`s on API levels 28 and below.

For the sake of illustration, we will use the following simplified layout, which we'll imagine ends up looking exactly like the example image above:

```xml
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tower">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/target"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_round_rectangle"
        android:backgroundTint="#602B608A"
        android:elevation="15dp"
        android:outlineProvider="background" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The `tower` image is [available here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVhN2.png), and the `shape_round_rectangle` drawable is simply:

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius" />
</shape>
```

Where `corner_radius` is `2dp`, in case you want your tests to look similar to the images here for comparison purposes. These values are all incidental, however, and you can use whatever you like, really.

Each example assumes that `parent` and `target` are assigned to appropriate `val`s of the same names; e.g.:

```kotlin
val parent = findViewById<ViewGroup>(R.id.parent)
val target = findViewById<View>(R.id.target)
```

We're going to draw our clipped shadows in `parent`'s `ViewGroupOverlay`, as this seems the most straightforward way to compactly demonstrate a general approach. Technically, this should work anywhere that you have access to a hardware-accelerated `Canvas` – e.g., in a custom `ViewGroup`'s `dispatchDraw()` override – though it may need some refactoring to apply it elsewhere.

Before beginning with the `RenderNode` section, it should be noted that each technique needs three basic things:

- An `Outline` object to describe the shadow's shape,
- A `Path` object of the same shape, to clip out the interior,
- Some mechanism by which to draw the shadow.

To that end, there is quite a bit of repetition across the two versions in order to keep them straightforward and plainly explanatory. You can obviously rearrange and consolidate things as you see fit, should you be implementing these side by side.

#### Method #1: `RenderNode` shadows

<sup>*(For the sake of brevity, this section assumes `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q` where needed.)*</sup>

For the `RenderNode` version on API levels 29 and up, `Canvas` offers the `drawRenderNode()` function, so we can handle the clipping and drawing both directly. As mentioned, we're doing this in the parent's overlay, and we can get access to the `Canvas` there with a simple `Drawable` subclass:

```kotlin
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
class ClippedShadowDrawable : Drawable() {
    private val outline = Outline().apply { alpha = 1.0F }
    private val clipPath = Path()
    private val renderNode = RenderNode("ClippedShadowDrawable")

    fun update(
        left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int,
        radius: Float, elevation: Float
    ) {
        setBounds(left, top, right, bottom)

        clipPath.rewind()
        clipPath.addRoundRect(
            left.toFloat(),
            top.toFloat(),
            right.toFloat(),
            bottom.toFloat(),
            radius,
            radius,
            Path.Direction.CW
        )

        outline.setRoundRect(0, 0, right - left, bottom - top, radius)
        renderNode.setOutline(outline)
        renderNode.setPosition(left, top, right, bottom)
        renderNode.elevation = elevation

        invalidateSelf()
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        if (!canvas.isHardwareAccelerated) return

        canvas.save()
        canvas.enableZ()
        canvas.clipOutPath(clipPath)
        canvas.drawRenderNode(renderNode)
        canvas.disableZ()
        canvas.restore()
    }

    // Unused
    override fun getOpacity() = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    override fun setAlpha(alpha: Int) {}
    override fun setColorFilter(colorFilter: ColorFilter?) {}
}
```

In addition to the aforementioned `Outline` and `Path` objects, we use a `RenderNode` here for the actual shadow draw. We also define an `update()` function that takes relevant values from the target `View` as a simple way to refresh those properties as needed.

You can see that the magic happens in the `draw()` override, and I think the code there explains itself quite clearly, though I will mention that the `en/disableZ()` functions basically tell the underlying native routine that the `RenderNode` should cast a shadow, if it qualifies.

To put it to use, we'll wire it up to the `parent` and `target` described in the Overview section above like so:

```kotlin
val clippedShadowDrawable = ClippedShadowDrawable()

target.setOnClickListener {
    if (target.tag != clippedShadowDrawable) {
        target.outlineProvider = null
        parent.overlay.add(clippedShadowDrawable)
        clippedShadowDrawable.update(
            target.left,
            target.top,
            target.right,
            target.bottom,
            resources.getDimension(R.dimen.corner_radius),
            target.elevation
        )
        target.tag = clippedShadowDrawable
    } else {
        target.outlineProvider = ViewOutlineProvider.BACKGROUND
        parent.overlay.remove(clippedShadowDrawable)
        target.tag = null
    }
}
```

The `OnClickListener` on the `target` will allow you to easily toggle the fix in order to compare and contrast its effect. We set the `target`'s `tag` to the `ClippedShadowDrawable` as a convenient flag to indicate whether the fix is currently enabled, hence the `if (target.tag != clippedShadowDrawable)` check first thing.

To turn the fix on, we need to:

- Set the `target`'s `ViewOutlineProvider` to null, to disable the intrinsic shadow,
- Add our custom `Drawable` to the `parent`'s overlay,
- Call its `update()` function,
- Set the `target`'s `tag` to the `ClippedShadowDrawable` instance as our *on* flag.

We turn it off by:

- Restoring the original `ViewOutlineProvider` on the `target`,
- Removing our custom `Drawable` from the `parent`'s overlay,
- Setting the `tag` back to `null`, flagging it as *off*.

That's all there is to it, but remember that this is demonstrating only the very basic core technique. The static setup and known values make accounting for the `target`'s state trivial, but things get complicated quickly if you need additional behaviors like adjusting for button presses or animations.

#### Method #2: `View` shadows

<sup>*(Though this one works on all applicable versions, these shadows didn't exist before Lollipop, so you might need some `SDK_INT` checks for that.)*</sup>

This approach is a little roundabout. Since we don't have direct access to `RenderNode`s here, we instead use an empty `View` for its intrinsic shadow. Unfortunately, we can't just directly `draw()` a `View` ourselves and have its shadow work as we would like, so we handle this somewhat passively: we add the empty `View` to a parent `ViewGroup` to let it draw via the normal routine while we clip and restore around that in the parent's `dispatchDraw()`.

To that end, our `ClippedShadowView` itself is actually a custom `ViewGroup` with another `View` inside:

```kotlin
class ClippedShadowView(context: Context) : ViewGroup(context) {
    private val outline = Outline().apply { alpha = 1.0F }
    private val clipPath = Path()
    private val shadowView = View(context)

    init {
        addView(shadowView)
        shadowView.outlineProvider = object : ViewOutlineProvider() {
            override fun getOutline(view: View, outline: Outline) {
                outline.set(this@ClippedShadowView.outline)
            }
        }
    }

    fun update(
        left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int,
        radius: Float, elevation: Float
    ) {
        clipPath.rewind()
        clipPath.addRoundRect(
            left.toFloat(),
            top.toFloat(),
            right.toFloat(),
            bottom.toFloat(),
            radius,
            radius,
            Path.Direction.CW
        )

        outline.setRoundRect(0, 0, right - left, bottom - top, radius)
        shadowView.layout(left, top, right, bottom)
        shadowView.elevation = elevation

        shadowView.invalidate()
    }

    override fun dispatchDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        if (!canvas.isHardwareAccelerated) return

        canvas.save()
        clipOutPath(canvas, clipPath)
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas)
        canvas.restore()
    }

    private fun clipOutPath(canvas: Canvas, path: Path) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            canvas.clipOutPath(path)
        } else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE)
        }
    }

    // Unused
    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int) {}
}
```

Unfortunately, there's no way to simply set an `Outline` on a `View`, so we have to use a custom `ViewOutlineProvider` on the `shadowView` to deliver it through that mechanism instead. After the `Outline` is refreshed in `update()`, the `shadowView` is invalidated, which will cause it to call through to the provider for the updated `Outline`.

In the `dispatchDraw()` override, we clip out the `Path` before calling the `super` function to let `ViewGroup` draw the `shadowView` as it normally would.

We wire this up in almost exactly the same way as the `RenderNode` setup, but with an additional call to `clippedShadowView.layout()`, since that's not laid out anywhere else:

```kotlin
val clippedShadowView = ClippedShadowView(target.context)

target.setOnClickListener {
    if (target.tag != clippedShadowView) {
        target.outlineProvider = null
        parent.overlay.add(clippedShadowView)
        clippedShadowView.layout(0, 0, parent.width, parent.height)
        clippedShadowView.update(
            target.left,
            target.top,
            target.right,
            target.bottom,
            resources.getDimension(R.dimen.corner_radius),
            target.elevation
        )
        target.tag = clippedShadowView
    } else {
        target.outlineProvider = ViewOutlineProvider.BACKGROUND
        parent.overlay.remove(clippedShadowView)
        target.tag = null
    }
}
```

#### Aftermath

Both methods result in exactly the same thing, taking into consideration the fact that shadows will vary slightly with their screen positions, due to the two-source rendering model:

[image: Screenshot of examples of both fixes, and an example with a fully transparent target.]

The top image shows the `RenderNode` fix in action, the middle is the `View` method, and the bottom one is what either would look like with a completely transparent target (or no target at all, actually) to make it easier to see exactly how the shadow is being clipped.

Comment: You did a fantastic job! So much things to research just to be able to do shadow on transparent views. Google should add something native for this goal.

Answer (score -1):

I had the similar issue. However, it all worked when I removed the line `cardBackgroundColor` and used `android:background="@color/transparent`. When you add or set the `cardBackgroundColor`, by default there is slight elevation which causes shadow opaque effect.