# How to create a shape with a transparent background and a shadow, but the shadow should not be visible behind the shape outline?

Tags: android, transparent, shadow

Somewhat similar question here but answer is to just remove elevation and shadow... not what I want: [Android CardView with weird border when transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624085/android-cardview-with-weird-border-when-transparent/31624267)

What I want is what is shown in the Pixel Launcher search bar... namely a shape which has a semi transparent background and also a shadow, but ***the shadow does not overlap with the white shape*** (which would end up making it look grey). I basically want a shadow but with a hole in the middle of it where my shape is...

This is what I want to achieve (the search bar down the bottom):
[image: What I want]

Here is what I have tried but you can see from the attached picture, that the grey shadow is coming through the semitransparent white background.

activity_main.xml

```
    <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="120dp"
      android:layout_height="120dp"
      android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
      android:elevation="8dp" />
```

Rectangle.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <corners android:radius="4dp" />
  <solid android:color="#aaffffff" />
</shape>
```

This is what my attempt looks like:
[image: My failed attempt]

You can see that even though my shape is semi transparent white on a white background, it turns grey because of the shadow underneath which is not what I want.

I have also tried playing with View#setOutlineProvider with no success.

I have also tried playing with https://github.com/harjot-oberai/MaterialShadows

I don't want to do it with a 9patch image if I can avoid it.

Comment: are you by any chance using it above the cardview?

Comment: your layout works perfectly fine as you want it to.

Comment: the gray shadow is the result of using elevation. try setting elevation value to `0dp`

Comment: @KaranMer correct, but that will also remove the shadow, which is wanted

Comment: did you tried using lesser value for elevation ex `2dp`? be more the elevation value more darker will be the shadow

Comment: @KaranMer I want a nice visible shadow though, and transparency without the grey tint.

Comment: Well you cannot change the elevation shadow color, following material design guidelines https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html#elevation-in-material-design   However, i can hack my way through it, if thats something u want

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to apply the transparency to the frame itself, not just the rectangle's background. This would create an effect similar to the one pictured.

For example:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:alpha="0.6" />
```

This of course has problems if you want non-transparent elements, to fix this you could extract out the background, and do something along the lines of:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:alpha="0.6"
        android:elevation="8dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```